# Invoking Web Activity failed with HttpStatusCode - '404 : NotFound' + Azure Synapse Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am trying to get the current pipeline runs using the web activity. I followed the below article, however, after having all the permissions required, it give the below error.

> Invoking Web Activity failed with HttpStatusCode - '404 : NotFound',
> message - 'The requested resource does not exist on the server. Please
> verify the request server and retry

link followed

https://www.moderndata.ai/2021/12/how-to-prevent-concurrent-pipeline-execution-in-azure-data-factory-or-azure-synapse-analytics-design-1/

Any idea why I am facing the above error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBAVR.png)

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs when you run the pipeline using `Debug` option from the top tool bar. It would work fine if you will run it using `Trigger Now` option.

When you try to query using the Web API, it only query the non-debug pipeline runs, means only triggered runs. Therefore, run it using trigger.

Comment: I did tried both ways, but still facing the same issue.